# What is the keyboard shortcut to clear formatting on Office 2008 Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2008

I recently switched from a PC to a brand new Macbook Pro. I was happy to see that most of the keyboard shortcuts in Word 2008 where the same or almost the same than in Word 2007. However, there is one keyboard shortcut that I dearly miss : the clear formatting shortcut (ctrl + space on Windows). I know the feature exists since it's in the formatting bar, but I can't find the keyboard shorcut. I tried cmd + space but that is the system keyboard shortcut to switch the keyboard type. alt + space delete the text without deleting the formatting. ctrl + space doesn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone know what the keyboard shortcut for the clear formatting command may be?

I hope there's one because it's really painful to reach for the mouse everytime I put a title and I want to switch to a normal paragraph style...

Comment: I'm not sure that there is one. I believe there used to be a keyboard shortcut in older versions of Word for the Mac.

Comment: You can try changing the input source shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Keyboard & Text Input* to see if a Word shortcut exists but is overridden by the system. You might also need to change the Spotlight shortcut in *System Prefereces » Spotlight*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do it on Word 2008, but Word 2011 has the feature. Just press Ctrl + Space and the formatting will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply self selected keyboard shortcuts in word 2008 by going to Tools > Customize Keyboard. Under view there is the 'Demotetobodytext' command listed. You can give it any shortcut you would like as long as it does not conflict with other shortcuts in use.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:  COMMAND + SHIFT + Z

For other Word for Mac 2011 shortcuts see [Word keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Word-keyboard-shortcuts-c0ca851f-3d58-4ce0-9867-799df73666a7?CorrelationId=d54dbdac-111a-4d02-9a1c-8dafbf867adb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a keyboard shortcut, but a relatively easy way to remove formatting is to use the option in the Inspector Panel:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I already knew about that option, but thank you anyway ^^.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple + Shift + T** will clear formatting in most applications on the Mac.

Comment: This changes the email to not be HTML in Outlook for the Mac, not what the OP is asking